# Windows Phone application state after sleep and/or lock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I developed a Windows Phone 7.1 Application, everything works well and I'm very happy with it. Although... Having the phone fall asleep while the app is running or locking the phone while still in the app, and then unlocking/waking up the phone - The app closes and I have to relaunch it.

So this then comes down to how your app reacts from a sleep state. How does one handle this event and just let the app continue where it left off rather than closing the app and having to manually re-launch it?

It would also be great if at "PhoneWake" or whatever you'll call it I can run a few functions before the app continues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scenario you're describing is usually called "tombstoning". You should be able to find plenty of documentation if you make a search using this keyword.

Comment: @KooKiz - Thank you very much, didn't know the term, but I have found a bunch of helpful stuff on the web now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a free ebook that microsoft released about windows phone developement. Its extremely useful and It could probably answer this and many other questions you might have! you can download the book from this website: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx